# In vim8.2, is there any difference between using :term vs :shell?

Tags: terminal, shell

In vim 8.2, is there any difference between using `:terminal` versus `:shell` to run commands on shell? Or are they identical?

I would like to know if there are any specific use-cases for using `:shell` vs `:terminal` where one could be more effective than the other?

To me they kind of looks like almost identical with very slight changes. I am trying to find out the reasoning for having these 2 seperate commands and cases (if there are any) where one might shine over the other.

env variables, initilization steps they all look similar to me. (correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 2):

`:terminal` spawns a new shell in a Vim window, so you can see a program compiling or producing some output at the same time you edit another normal buffer. Also, by pressing `<CTRL-W>N`, Vim can operate on the read-only terminal buffer, with yanking, Vim navigation, etc.

`:shell` also spawns a new shell, but this is a full terminal window shell (it is not in the [Alternate Screen](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-The-Alternate-Screen-Buffer) as Vim) that won't interacact with the underlying Vim. One can only switch back to Vim by terminating that shell. Unlike `:terminal`, `:shell` is not a Vim extension as it is in the [POSIX specification of Vi](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html) (indirectly, since it is an [Ex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) command), and so a Vim compiled with minimal features ([vim-tiny](https://packages.debian.org/buster/vim-tiny) in Ubuntu and Debian) will only have `:shell`.

`:shell` is very similar to `:suspend`/`<CTRL-Z>`, which uses the shell's job control to suspend Vim. But there are differences:

- Suspending is impossible in a terminal without a controlling shell (e.g. `xterm -e vim`).
- `:shell` spawns a new shell, which does not have access to Vim's parent shell local values, such as history and variables, whereas each suspenion always brings the same shell back. Indeed, you can toggle between the *same* shell and Vim with `<CTRL-Z>` and `fg`.